# How to get the first N result from google search using C#?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

How to get the first N result from google search using c#?

```
using (var webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            const string url = "https://www.google.com.au/search?num=100&q=my+search+term";
            var  result = webclient.DownloadString(url);
        }
```

Update:

How can I get where and how many times a specific url appeared ?

Comment: Show us some code of what you have already tried and not just some code you have copy pasted from other threads. we are here to help. Not to do your job/homework.

Comment: You can manually parse the html coming back just like your typical "screen scraper".  This will require you to understand the google response html format and will also potentially break your code if their DOM structure changes.

Answer (score 3):

The following will return the first 100 result of searching 'my search term' and return the order of a specified target 'mytarget'

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string Url = "http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=my+search+term";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = new HtmlWeb().Load(Url);
        var nodes = result.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//html//body//div[@class='g']");
        var indexes = nodes == null
                          ? new List<int> { 0 }
                          : nodes.Select((x, i) => new { i, x.InnerHtml })
                                .Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("mytarget"))
                                .Select(x => x.i + 1)
                                .ToList();


        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", indexes));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

another way to do it using regex:

```
 string html;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            html = webClient.DownloadString(searchUrl);
        }

        var regex = new Regex("<div class=\"g\">(.*?)</div>");

        var matches = regex.Matches(html).Cast<Match>().ToList();

        var indexes = matches.Select((x, i) => new { i, x })
            .Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("mytarget"))
            .Select(x => x.i + 1)
            .ToList();
```